# Gradle get 'sudo' rights

Tags: java, unix, gradle, war

I have next problem : I need execute some deployment stuff on server using Gradle, but for this Gradle should have 'root' access on target deployment server. I have password for 'sudo', but I don't know how to insert it in server.

Is there any way to get 'sudo' rights from Gradle task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The action you try to invoke is a commandline command, right? One solution might be to put this command in the sudoers file with your server user and the option no password needed. Don't know if there are any security constraints that will prohibit this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for a comment. Yeh, I'm need invoke this command from comandline. Is there any way without server machine file modification? It would be match more better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: since the commandline execution will be a sub-process and you might not have sudo rights on gradle (which would lead to further permissions problem with the outcoming artifacts), I don't see any way to achieve this from gradle. One hack solution might be a simple bash script called by gradle with the use of expect to pipe your **PLAIN** password (from the script) to the command line.

Comment: Thanks. But what if not Gradle would call the script, but script with 'sudo' right will run Gradle build script, How do you think : can such approach help?

Comment: I don't think that this approach will be successful: The _script with sudo rights_ will launch gradle with sudo rights and any 'sub-command' might (I am not 100% sure) run with this privileges. So all of your files in the output folder are owned by root. This will lead to a pretty privilege mess in your working directory. If you don't care about this, give it a try ;)