# Execute Gradle's Java run application with sudo rights

Tags: java, gradle, sudo

I have a run block defined as follows:

```
run {
    mainClassName = "com.example.Runner"
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xmx768M",
                                 "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"]
    args 'start'
}
```

How can I force `gradle run` to accquire sudo rights first before executing? I get the same behavior with `sudo gradle run`, but I would like to code this prerequisite and automate it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467754/gradle-get-sudo-rights even though it does not seem to have a good answer for you !

Comment: To run a gradle as root is not a good idea in any way, but it seems to be not possible, to make a single task run with root privileges. I know only one way to do it, but it's could be an overkill - is to use gradle-ssh-plugin and make your own task, wich will connect to localhost as root and execute a command you need.